# Why does setting variable to concatenation of PHP_EOL and a string throw an error?

Tags: php

In PHP, I get the following error when I try to create a class variable (`const`, `static` or even `private`) that is a concatenation of PHP_EOL and a string.

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '.', expecting ',' or ';'
```

The following all cause this:

```
private $myVar = PHP_EOL . "something";
const MYVAR = PHP_EOL . "something";
static $myVar = PHP_EOL . "something";

private $myVar = "something" . PHP_EOL;
const MYVAR = "something" . PHP_EOL;
static $myVar = "something" . PHP_EOL;
```

Changing to any of the following gets rid of the error:

```
private $myVar = PHP_EOL;
const MYVAR = PHP_EOL;
static $myVar = PHP_EOL;

private $myVar = "something";
const MYVAR = "something";
static $myVar = "something";
```

Why is concatenating PHP_EOL and a string not allowed when setting a variable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't create a constant using a constant.

Alternatively you can use the define method with a constant to create a global constant

```
define("MY_CONSTANT", PHP_EOL);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works too.

```
$endofLine = PHP_EOL;
$concat = $endofLine."somethingelse";
echo $concat;
```

Comment: my question is with regard to defining class members where it doesn't work